# Regex allowing a-zA-Z0-9, spaces, dots, commas, minus and not allowing newline

Tags: regex

I want to make regex that works for online sentence and can include:

- a-zA-Z
- 0-9
- spaces
- dots
- minus sign
- commas

I tried formula like this:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\s,.\r\n-]+$
```

But it does not work for input with newlines "dsa\nsad"

Can anybody explain me what is wrong and how to do it correctly?

Comment: I think you need `^[a-zA-Z0-9 .,-]+$`. What char do you have in mind when saying "minus sign"? [`\u2012`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=%E2%80%92) or [`\x2D`](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/?charlist=-)?

Comment: Probably \x2D
\u2012 I do not even know how to type tbh - it is dependent on the operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current regex is matching any whitespace by including `\s` in the character class.  Therefore, it is superfluous to also include `\r` and `\n`, and you might as well just use:

```regex
^[A-Za-z0-9\s,.-]+$
```

That aside, your pattern is working if you test it with an input containing an actual linefeed instead of `\n`.

### Demo